# failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error in

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have this error in my file Doc when I tried to download my file
 [image]

This is my code:

```
public function downloadAction()
{
    $id = $this->getParam("id");
    $req = Baseco::getBasecoById($id);
    $url = 'http://'.$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'].$this->view->baseUrl();
    $chemin = $url.$req->chemin;
    $type = FAR_Traitement_Fichier::getTypeFichier($req->type);

    header("Content-Type: $type");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=".basename($chemin));
    readfile($chemin);

    // disable layout and view
    $this->view->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender(true);
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Might help if you log the path of the file before trying to read it.

Comment: @Gábor Bakos I don't understand , how i can do that ?

Comment: Sorry, I missed the info on the screenshot. I am not sure `readfile` can load from a(n http) URL. Have you checked its documentation (http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php)?

Comment: have you tried `readfile(str_replace(" ", "%20", $filename));` ? -- edit: corrected the code